# Migrate .NET 2.0 application using file system storage to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an old ASP.NET 2.0 site that I really have no interest in rebuilding or updating at this point. I'd like to move it to Windows Azure but I'm not all that familiar with Azure so I'm wondering if it's easily portable.

The biggest potential roadblock is the fact that users can upload multiple photos. Upon upload, I create several copies of the image in pre-defined dimensions and store them on the local file system using Server.MapPath("{location}") to indicate where it should be stored.

- Can I have a site hosted on Azure (using their Free or Shared tier) and continue to use this method of uploading and storing files or do I have to switch to blob storage? There are only about 400MB of images.

Basically I'm looking for a low/no-cost way to easily host this site on Azure that doesn't involve changes to the code (or at the very least, extremely minimal changes such as changing Server.MapPath to some relative location) so that I can move my other, more current ones to Azure as well. My situation is such that if I can't move this site, it doesn't make sense to move the others because I'll have to keep paying for the server for this one anyways (they're all hosted on the same server for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure drives are not guaranteed to be stored between reboots of the virtual machine, so you will probably need to use blob storage. But you can [mount a blob as a NTFS volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156162.aspx) and store it there. This would make the transition quite simple in the code.